# Three.js freezes CSS animated background images and transitions

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, three.js

I've run into issue with **Three.js** (WebGL) - it freezes background animations (`.gif` in my case) and CSS transitions? Bascially when i don't trigger any CSS transition, the background GIF seems to freeze... but when I do trigger CSS transition (literally any), everything seems to move/animate/transition like it should. First time seeing this, so I would appreciate any help on debugging this and explaining me why does it act that way!? Should i set up some kind of delta time for `animate()`?

Here is my code example (try hovering menu, to see the issue with bg):

```js
/**
 * Hero Canvas
 */
var heroCanvasWrap = document.getElementById('hero-canvas');

THREE.Cache.enabled = true;

let container;

let camera, scene, renderer;

let group, textMesh1, textGeo, materials;

let text = "three.js",
    bevelEnabled = true,
    font = undefined;

const height = 20,
    size = 70,
    curveSegments = 4,
    bevelThickness = 2,
    bevelSize = 1.5;

const fontMap = {
    "helvetiker": 0,
    "optimer": 1,
    "gentilis": 2,
    "droid/droid_sans": 3,
    "droid/droid_serif": 4
};

const weightMap = {
    "regular": 0,
    "bold": 1

};

const reverseFontMap = [];
const reverseWeightMap = [];

for ( const i in fontMap ) reverseFontMap[ fontMap[ i ] ] = i;
for ( const i in weightMap ) reverseWeightMap[ weightMap[ i ] ] = i;

let targetRotation = 0;
let targetRotationOnPointerDown = 0;

let pointerX = 0;
let pointerXOnPointerDown = 0;

let windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;

let fontIndex = 1;

init();
animate();

function decimalToHex( d ) {

    let hex = Number( d ).toString( 16 );
    hex = "000000".substr( 0, 6 - hex.length ) + hex;
    return hex.toUpperCase();

}

function init() {

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    heroCanvasWrap.appendChild( container );

    // CAMERA

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1500 );
    camera.position.set( 0, 100, 500 );

    // cameraTarget = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 150, 0 );

    // SCENE

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // LIGHTS

    const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.75 );
    dirLight.position.set( 0, 0, 70 ).normalize();
    scene.add( dirLight );

    // Get text from hash

    

    materials = [
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xE1885D } )
    ];

    group = new THREE.Group();
    group.position.y = 100;

    scene.add( group );

    const loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
    loader.load( 'http://localhost:1234/montserrat-bold.json', function ( response ) {

        font = response;

        refreshText();

    } );



    // RENDERER

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha:true, antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    // EVENTS
    container.style.touchAction = 'none';
}

function createText() {

    textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( text, {

        font: font,

        size: size,
        height: height,
        curveSegments: curveSegments,

        bevelThickness: bevelThickness,
        bevelSize: bevelSize,
        bevelEnabled: bevelEnabled

    } );

    textGeo.computeBoundingBox();

    const centerOffset = - 0.5 * ( textGeo.boundingBox.max.x - textGeo.boundingBox.min.x );

    textMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( textGeo, materials );

    textMesh1.position.x = centerOffset;

    group.add( textMesh1 );

}

function refreshText() {

    group.remove( textMesh1 );

    if ( ! text ) return;

    createText();

}

//

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();

}

function render() {

    group.rotation.y += ( targetRotation - group.rotation.y ) * 0.05;

    // camera.lookAt( cameraTarget );

    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

/**
 * Document is ready?
 * @param {*} callbackFunc 
 */
function ready(callbackFunc) {
    if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
      // Document is already ready, call the callback directly
      callbackFunc();
    } else if (document.addEventListener) {
      // All modern browsers to register DOMContentLoaded
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callbackFunc);
    } else {
      // Old IE browsers
      document.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', function() {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
          callbackFunc();
        }
      });
    }
}

/**
 * Document is redy! Init js...
 */
ready(function() {
    /**
     * Toggle light/dark mode
     */
    var lightToggle = document.querySelector('.light-toggle'),
        theBody = document.body;

    lightToggle.onclick = function() {
        theBody.classList.toggle('dark');
    }



    /**
     * Toggle main menu
     */
    var toggleMenu = document.querySelector('.toggle-menu'),
        toggleMenuContent = document.getElementById('toggle-menu-content'),
        headerHead = document.querySelector('header.head');

    toggleMenu.onclick = function() {
            /* theBody.classList.toggle('overflow-hidden'); */
        headerHead.classList.toggle('fixed');
        toggleMenuContent.classList.toggle('open');
    }
});
```

```css
/** Tailwind **/
@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.3/tailwind.min.css';
/** Montserrat Font **/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');


/**
 * MAIN
 **/
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/mGVpddB/bg.gif");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

a:focus,
button:focus{
  outline: none !important; /** Remove all link & button outlines **/
}

/** Fullscreen helper **/
.fullscreen-bg {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  /* background-attachment: fixed; */
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: italic;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  z-index: 10;
}

.btn.btn-slash::before{
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) skewX(25deg);
  background: #DBDBDB;
  width: 10px;
  height: 45px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.btn.btn-slash:hover::before{
  width: 80%;
}

/* HERO */

.light-toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 30.422px;
  height: 31.898px;
  z-index: 300;
}

.light-toggle::before,
.light-toggle::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30.422px;
  height: 31.898px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -15.949px;
}

.light-toggle::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='30.422' height='31.898' viewBox='0 0 30.422 31.898'%3E%3Cpath class='a' d='M11.576,54A15.415,15.415,0,0,1,1.269,50.192a12.031,12.031,0,0,1,0-18.385A15.415,15.415,0,0,1,11.576,28a16.274,16.274,0,0,1,3.924.477,14.859,14.859,0,0,0-7.63,4.6,11.906,11.906,0,0,0,0,15.853,14.86,14.86,0,0,0,7.63,4.6A16.273,16.273,0,0,1,11.576,54Z' transform='matrix(0.799, -0.602, 0.602, 0.799, -14.455, -13.034)' style='fill:gray;'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
}

#toggle-menu-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#toggle-menu-content.open {
  height: 100% !important;
}

#toggle-menu-content footer .light-toggle{
  margin-top: 35px;
}

header.head {
  position: absolute;
}
header.head.fixed {
  z-index: 300;
}

.menu-links li {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.menu-links li a {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.menu-links li a {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.menu-links li a:hover {
  margin-left: -25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
.menu-links li.active {
  margin-left: -80px !important;
}
.menu-links li.active a:hover {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
.menu-links li.active a {
  color: #E1885D;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: italic;
}
.menu-links li.active a::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
/** Footer **/
footer address a {
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.socials li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.socials li a {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #808080;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.socials li a .dot {
  color: #FA1DA5;
}




/**
 * MAIN / DARK
 **/
body.dark {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  background-color: #000000 !important;
  background-image: url("../img/dark-bg.gif") !important;
}
.dark .btn.btn-slash {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.dark .btn.btn-slash::before {
  background: #4D4D4D;
}
.dark .footer-logo path,
.dark .footer-logo rect {
  fill: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.3/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r125/three.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>EC</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  </head>

  <body>  
    <nav id="toggle-menu-content">
      <header class="p-36">
          <ul class="menu-links">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">īsumā</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">pratība</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">paveiktais</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">klienti & draugi</a></li>
          </ul>
      </header>

      <footer class="pl-36 pr-12 py-20 grid grid-cols-6 gap-x-24">
          <div class="col-span-3"></div>

          <div class="relative col-start-5 col-end-7">
              <div class="absolute bottom-0 right-0">
                  <ul class="socials relative inline float-right">
                      <li><a href="#">ig<span class="dot">.</span></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">fb<span class="dot">.</span></a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <button class="light-toggle mr-12"></button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </footer>
  </nav>
  <header id="hero" class="relative w-full h-full">
      <header class="head top-0 left-0 w-full p-12 z-20">
          <nav class="menu float-right">
              <button class="btn btn-slash hover toggle-menu"><span class="relative z-10">menu</span></button>
          </nav>
      </header>

      <main id="hero-canvas" class="relative clear-both w-full h-full">
      </main>
  </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Just in case if it's due to browser support, here is video screenshot how it looks on my end:

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 0px; position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.250%;"><iframe src="https://streamable.com/e/npetvt" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;"></iframe></div>
```

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: Everything continues running for me. The "static", the "stretching" on mouse-over, and the translation of the strings when the menue is open. All of it runs continuously for me. Chrome 88.0.4324.150 x64

Comment: I just tested Firefox 85.0.2 on a Windows 10 machine, and the background "noise" gif also animates for me without any problem.

Comment: I'm running Firefox Developer 86.0b8 (64-bit). Double checked on Chrome Dev (latest), Edge and Safari, works too. I guess I'm reporting this as bug for latest Firefox Dev.